# Test Leetcode 104. Maximum Depth of Binary Tree

Tags: python-3.x

I am testing the leetcode 104 Maximum Depth of Binary Tree. While testing the case root = [3,9,20,None, None,15,7] . The output should be 3 but it shows 2. Could someone help me with this. Thanks

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,val=0, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left        
        self.right = right
    
def createTreeNode(nodeList):
    root = TreeNode(nodeList[0])
    root.left = TreeNode(nodeList[1])
    root.right = TreeNode(nodeList[2]) 
    return root        

def maxDepth(root):
    if root is None:
        return 0
    else:
        max_left = maxDepth(root.left)
        max_right = maxDepth(root.right)
        return max(max_left, max_right) + 1

def main():    
    ListNode1 = [3,9,20,None,None,15,7]
    TreeNode1 = createTreeNode(ListNode1)
    print (maxDepth(TreeNode1))
main()
```

Comment: Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program in any way? When you do, what does that tell you?

Comment: You aren't constructing the full tree. You are only constructing the root node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not construct your tree in the right way. Leetcode recently added an option to visualize trees (see Tree Visualizer in the right-bottom corner of the Testcase tab). For your input:

[image]

In test cases usually trees are represented as in-order traversal, so you can build up a tree from it using suitable traversal algorithm or you could build it manually:

```
root = TreeNode(3)
root.left = TreeNode(9)
root.right = TreeNode(20)
root.right.right = TreeNode(7)
root.right.left = TreeNode(15)
```

Your algorithm is correct, but I would refactor it a bit:

```
def maxDepth(root):
    if not root:
        return 0
    max_left = maxDepth(root.left)
    max_right = maxDepth(root.right)
    return max(max_left, max_right) + 1
```